# Using input in notebook TOC to Open at page 50 of a notebook

Tags: notebooks

Already I have made a Table of Contents (TOC) notebook.  In it are buttons which when pressed load very long notebooks, like say notebook ZZZ, which contains research notes.  TOC works great.

Unfortunately the buttons ALWAYS default to the first cell of notebook ZZZ.  I do not want to open there.  Instead I always want to open notebook ZZZ at some "pointer xx" far inside the notebook, for example on page 132 of notebook ZZZ, or open to a specific text string in the notebook ZZZ if pointers are impractical.

For example, if I will give a lecture on "monopoly" I want a button in TOC which will load my microeconomics class lectures notebook ZZZ AND, as part of opening it, will scroll down to where the text "monopoly behavior" occurs which happens to be roughly on page 145 of that notebook.

I have worked many hours spread over several years trying to find a way to do this, which would be incredibly useful either for lectures or to organize research notes. No luck so far.

Help please?

Comment: Se a `CellTag` on a `Section` and use `NotebookLocate` to scroll to it. This can be used to open a notebook directly to a tag, too, so you don't need to open the notebook first.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include either your TOC notebook code or a link to the code.